# How to add If Modified Since HTTP header in every request of a webpage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httprequest

I am trying to add `If Modified Since HTTP header` in RequestHeader of each file in a webpage e.g. in each css/js/image etc.

I tried as shown in [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_headers.html#page-header)

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  RequestHeader append If-Modified-Since "Thu, 18 Jan 2018 12:33:10 GMT"
</ifModule>
```

But, it is not adding any new parameter to RequestHeader.

Comment: The client needs to add those headers, it makes little sense to add them on the server, unless you're in some specific situation which you aren't telling us. You need to set the correct last-modified and cache handling headers, then the client will inquire with an if-modified-since header itself.

Comment: @deceze yes you are right actually i was trying in wrong direction.